# Opening a new powershell window with a CMD command

Tags: powershell, dos

Lets say I have the following:

```
    $a = 1.1.1.1
```

cmd /C "mode con:cols=55 lines=10 && title Google && ping 1.1.1.1 -t"

I need to be able to open a cmd window from powershell and pass it the `"cmd /C "mode con:cols=55 lines=10 && title Google && ping 1.1.1.1 -t""`

But i also want to be able to replace the ip address in the passed command to a variable like so `cmd /C "mode con:cols=55 lines=10 && title Google && ping " + $a + " -t"`

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `Start-Process` commandlet and build your argument strings as necessary:

```
start-process cmd -ArgumentList "/C","mode con:cols=55 lines=10 && title Google && ping $a -t"
```

Comment: Oh My God Thank you, I have been face desking forever.